# Specify the mip_solver corresponding executable while using gdpopt pyomo

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, solver, pyomo, glpk

Can someone help me with the following? I need to specify the path to the executable solver when using gdpopt in pyomo

Normally for glpk solver one can specify this path in SolverFactory as:

`executable_path = '/home/user/lib/glpsol'`

`opt = SolverFactory('glpk',executable=executable_path)`

But this desn't work if I want to use gdpopt and specify the executable of glpk in the same way as in the following example:

`opt = SolverFactory('gdpopt',executable=executable_path)`

I have tried using the `mip_solver_args` parameter as follows but I had no luck.

`opt = SolverFactory('gdpopt')`

`results = opt.solve(model, mip_solver='glpk', mip_solver_args={'executable':executable_path})`

Finally, I tried the same with the cbc solver but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current solver parameters for GDPopt don't allow for specifying the executable argument in the `SolverFactory` call. I don't have the bandwidth right now to go through the PR process for a new solver option, but the benefit of open-source is that you can modify your installation of Pyomo to include the desired `executable=` argument.

You will need to search for `SolverFactory` calls made in the `mip_solve.py` file: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/main/pyomo/contrib/gdpopt/mip_solve.py. This file should be responsible for any MIP subsolver calls that GDPopt makes. From there, you can change the `SolverFactory` calls in the file to include your `executable=executable_path` for `glpk` or `cbc`, respectively, as you wish.